# Most of the Bitcoin exchanges, are they using 3rd party API like blockchain.info or running their own node?

Tags: exchanges

I'd like to know how the bitcoin exchanges work. It's not about big exchanges like binance or bittrex. I'd like to know people could make an exchange solely relay on third party apis and are they safe ?

Answer (score 2):

> Most of the Bitcoin exchanges, are they using 3rd party API like
>   blockchain.info or running their own node?

They're running own nodes.

> I'd like to know people could make an exchange solely relay on third
>   party apis and are they safe ?

In my own opinion it's not safe to delegate service to third party services in case of money, especially if you can create and run that's service byself.

Comment: Thanks, is there any opensource bitcoin node I can try it on my server. Bitcoin core is something like GUI based desktop application.

Comment: All that you need is https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoind

Comment: You may want to checkout https://bitcore.io/guides as well, as it abstracts a lot of the difficulties when building apps on top of bitcoind.